# Translating each result row of a Google Sheets QUERY operation via VLOOKUP

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

I have the multi-column results of a `QUERY` in Google Sheets, where I want to translate the strings in one column based on a lookup table in another named range. I can accomplish this indirectly with an additional `VLOOKUP` call, but I'd like to do it all in one go, with no intermediary steps. See [this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IWXbmYecyCeGFI1c5v9fC4qMauCGZ3u3EtbeiNX45UA/edit#gid=0) for an example of my format.

The initial query I make looks something like this:

```
=QUERY(votes, "SELECT B, SUM(C) GROUP BY B LABEL B 'Option', SUM(C) 'Votes'")
```

I can then translate each row with something like this in a new column...

```
=VLOOKUP(A2, options, 2, 0)
```

... and then just pick out the columns I need:

```
={C2:C4,B2:B4}
```

How can I combine all this? I think I need to do this with an `ARRAYFORMULA`, but this doesn't seem to be it:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(options, QUERY(votes, "SELECT B, SUM(C) GROUP BY B LABEL B 'Option', SUM(C) 'Votes'"), 2, FALSE))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({VLOOKUP(INDEX(
 QUERY(votes, "select B,sum(C) group by B LABEL sum(C)''"),,1), options, 2, 0), 
 QUERY(votes, "select   sum(C) group by B LABEL sum(C)''")})
```

[image: 0]

Comment: My actual query out of the source data needed some additional filtering, so this one worked for me. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Votes!B2:B, options, 2, 0)), Votes!C2:C}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''", 0))
```

[image: 0]